# Problems using the while loop

Tags: c++

Given positive integer numInsects, write a while loop that prints that number doubled without reaching 100. Follow each number with a space. After the loop, print a newline. Ex: If numInsects = 8, print:

8 16 32 64

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int numInsects = 0;

   numInsects = 8; // Must be >= 1

   while (numInsects < 100) {

   numInsects = numInsects * 2;



   cout << numInsects << " ";

   }

   cout << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

I have been getting an output of: 16 32 64 128
I am fully aware of how I got that output I just don't know how to get the starting value at 8.

Comment: Try tracing your code with a debugger or (in this case since it's really simple code) manually. It'll force you to see what's going on with your code.

Answer (score 7):

Move *cout* before recalculating numInsects
Eg:

```
while (numInsects < 100) {
    cout << numInsects << " ";
    numInsects = numInsects * 2;
}
```

Comment: Of course, sorry for such a simple question. First couple weeks of learning C++.